# Write integration testing for console application calling post method to a webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nunit, integration-testing

I have developed a console application which takes input from the user and make a post method to webapi and return complex object as response.
I want to write an integration test for this.

As I am completely new to writing testing, can someone help me to write an integration test for this scenario?

Comment: Are you trying to test console application or webapi service?

Comment: want to write integration test. so test console app and webapi